# CONNECT ERROR: When trying to install Fooman Speedster Advanced

Tags: error, extensions, magento-connect

I'm attempting to install Fooman Speedster Advanced for a client's site but to no avail, I keep recieving the below error when attempting to install.

Has anyone had this before and if so how did you fix it? See below the logs from Magento Connect.

> Checking dependencies of packages Starting to download
>   Fooman_SpeedsterAdvanced-0.8.9-beta.tgz ...
>
> CONNECT ERROR: Package not found: Fooman_SpeedsterAdvanced 0.8.9-beta
>   Package 'Fooman_Common' is invalid
>   './app/code/community/Fooman/Common/Block/Adminhtml/Extensioninfo.php'
>   already exists

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....